# How to map the jsonDecode return with User Class in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, mapping

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserDetails(String accessToken) async {
    final url = 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN/userinfo';
    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get user details');
    }
  }
```

How can I get this return value **jsonDecode(response.body)** to Map with the **User class** so I can access the name and email in another dart file.

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
      };
}
```

The **getUserDetails** is in auth.dart file, the **User class** is in another dart file and I have to access ***name and email*** in another dart file. PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

Just call first the request like that:

```
var response = await ClassAuth().getUserDetails(token);
```

And then parse data to user object:

```
User user = User.fromJson(response);
String email = user.email;
```

Comment: I am getting email as null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Provider package to solve this problem.
You can put your value and then get it from a child widget of  auth provider.